# Transition from tableView to another View shines through

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

In my app I have posts in a tableview and when I click on a post, a segue brings in another view controller with a detailed view of the post. When my background color is any other color than black, everything works fine. But when I use a black background, you can always see the tableview shine through during the process of transitioning. After like a second the transparent part goes away and everything is good, but that makes the transition look very bad. I have a picture of what I mean, this is the detailed view. All pics and text are random and just for testing the app (so no my posts don't get 2.302 comments :D)

[Detailed ViewController Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjJI.png)

Comment: please share your code. It's difficult to help you this way

Comment: I don't have any code for that, because I just set up the segue in my storyboard, so sorry about that. Maybe someone know why thats only happening with the black background or maybe someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the opacity in the segue function as desired.

Comment: the opacity of the destination view controller or of the tableview?

Comment: the destination as that's the one that is showing it's background.

Comment: I put the following code, but it gives me an error. Seems like it can't find the view. But DoubleDetailViewController is a subclass of UIViewController?! 

let destinationVC:DoubleDetailViewController = segue.destination as! DoubleDetailViewController
            destinationVC.view.alpha = 1

Comment: Sorry I am kinda new to App-Development, what do you mean by 'hosted on a public repo' ? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I found my problem, it was the alpha value of the background color. Thanks anyways, I will mark your answer as right.

Comment: Nice work... Well then the alpha wasn't dark enough to begin with, and you happened to notice it on the segue.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem, alpha was just 0.8.. still appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Maybe next time print the value out in viewDidLoad, and then again in the segue. Then you can see how its messing with you :-)